# Metrics/ParameterLists error in too many method params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an API resource to fetch transaction list. There are few filters and params to make it sortable e.g. `per_page`, `status` etc. which may be passed on but only `user_id` is required. Now my method looks like this:

```
def list(user_id:, page: nil, per_page: nil, status: nil, payment_id: nil, start_date: nil,
         end_date: nil, max_amount: nil)

  filters = { start_date:, end_date:, max_amount:, status:, payment_id: }.compact_blank!
  params = { filters:, page:, per_page: }.compact_blank!

  begin
    body = get("users/#{user_id}/transactions", params:).body
  rescue Errors::NotFoundError
    nil
  end
  resource_list(body, BaseStruct::Transaction)
end
```

This code produces me Rubocop error of:
`Metrics/ParameterLists: Avoid parameter lists longer than 5 parameters. [8/5]`. I know I could get rid of it by `# rubocop:disable Metrics/ParameterLists` but I don't think that's the best idea. Is it possible to pass those not required field in a different way to avoid that error?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing 3 kinds of parameters to the `list` method, you can group them and pass them to the method like below:

```
def list(user_id, filter_params, page_params)
  filters = filter_params.compact_blank!
  params = { filter_params, page_params.slice(:page), page_params.slice(:per_page) }.compact_blank!

  begin
    body = get("users/#{user_id}/transactions", params).body
  rescue Errors::NotFoundError
    nil
  end
  resource_list(body, BaseStruct::Transaction)
end

list(user_id, { status: nil, payment_id: nil, start_date: nil, end_date: nil, max_amount: nil }, { page: nil, per_page: nil })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [CountKeywordArgs option](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_metrics.html#countkeywordargs-true-default) that I found useful to set false.

My rationale is that kwargs add less complexity than positional or optional parameters. It's more effective replacement of old-school Hash `options` argument.